# switch case runs a case which is not the case

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

i am preparung for exams in programming java I. In this exercise I am supposed to run the code by myself and say what comes out.
This code is given by the professor of my course. I didn't create this code.

Following is the code:

```
public class SS13Aufg2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        while (a < 6) {
            a = a + 2;
            switch (a%3) {
                case 0 : b = a-b;
                case 1 : b = a*b;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

What I am not able to unterstand, is already in the first time of run through. a = 3 --> a%3 is 0 and case 0 comes out. But after that the program runs case 1 as well. Why? it is not the case.

Comment: Did you forget a break for each case?

Comment: See also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: This is not my code, it is the code of my prof. I am just supposed to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `break` here. And having a default case is ideal.

```
switch (a%3) {
    case 0 : b = a-b;
        break;
    case 1 : b = a*b;
        break;
    default:System.out.println("Invalid");          
        break;
}
```

Read [more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Comment: Use break statement after each case ending as Ruchira mentioned

Comment: You might also want a default case, that raises an error of some kind.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen yes. it is.

Comment: No you understodd me wrong, this code is given by the professor of my course. And I am supposed to run it by myself. I didn't create this code. I am just wondering because it is just doing it the first time.